# Do countries frame their contributions in climate change negotations in reference to others?

Tags: international-relations, international

I am curious if there are recent examples of countries framing their actions against climate change in reference to other countries? Like compared to China the US does such an such.

I am aware of many cases, where it is framed to the global average or the global amount of current or past emissions, but curious about compared to other countries.

Comment: Clarifying question. Are you asking only if countries do this?  Because third-party skeptics in the US often frame some of the debate on the leading producers of CO2, like China, being exempt from any and all regulations in climate negotiations

Comment: Who would compare to China or the US? Aren't we the biggest contributers and the most stubborn about making commitments? "I'm a better parent than the tweekers down the street"

Comment: This seems more like a research request rather than an actual political question.

Answer (score -2):

> Like compared to China the US does such an such.

Current climate agreements are structured as declines off of current emissions, thus favoring developed countries.

In terms of total emission (of greenhouse gases), China, US, Europe, India and Russia round up as the top 5.

in terms of per capita emission, Canada, US, Russia, Japan and Europe as the top 5. India ranked way below world average.

if you believe in equality, you should go by per capita numbers: tough to argue why an Indian citizen doesn't deserve to enjoy as much energy consumption as a French citizen or a Canadian.

But that's not how most people in the developed countries think.

Comment: There are parts of truth in this answer (in the treaties I remember developing countries were given more leniency due of their lower per capita consumption, and because clean alternatives were more expensive) but you should try to focus more in the data and less in your opinion.